# How should I store a php user object for use by many classes?

Tags: php, variables, object, scope, global-variables

So currently I am building a site with a login. I
+- access a user object for any user who is logged in, so in this object there are things like preferences, avatar, name, passhash etc.

I use a MVC style for the application and what is bothering me is that from first initialization I check for sessions or cookies, retrieve the user info from my DB to verify, then I store a simple session ID that links to that specific user in the DB.

As it stands though, I have to call my user class for one purpose usually and that is to retrieve the user's info, but because I have a complex hierarchy and many classes, I would have to pass this data to every class who uses it, or hit up the DB 9 times for the same info.

I read somewhere that it is very bad to store user data in a global variable for security reasons, but I'm not sure what my alternative would be in this situation, and I was hoping someone here would have more experience and a better Idea.

EDIT: After further research and reading similar questions, I have stumbled upon serialize() which seems like it could be a very useful function, but I still wanted to post this question while I work with it and see if this is a possible solution.

Comment: why is a global variable a security issue? every php script is independent of every other php script, and once any particular execution run finishes, everything gets cleaned up/destroyed. parallel executions have no access to each other's data.

Comment: What is the reason for not passing the object as a parameter to any function which requires the data, as far it is running in a single request? Is this a question about object handling or about optimization?

Comment: @MarcB "The use of global is strongly not recommended." - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604779/how-can-i-make-a-regular-variable-accessible-in-files-included-by-a-class-method
"The question is are they bad practice. The answer is 'yes, sometimes'. ... for larger projects with many team members and lots of moving parts, heavy use of global variables will make the code difficult to debug, nearly impossible to refactor, and a pain to even read. Can you use them sometimes,.. sure - do they kina suck,.. yeah!"

Comment: @syck I am using a MVC style. Some of my models require user data but I already retrieve a user object in init.php, the first required file in my structure when I check for a cookie and set session data if one is found. This will give me a user object which I would love to use, but My controller instantiation does not have the functionality to pass this object to my controller where i check to see if the user is logged in. I also need the data for some of the models which I already pass an array of data to. So there are 3 instances of the same class and the same object being built in one load.

Comment: If your framework forces you to act this way, you could still cache the object data inside the class (and return them on the next call with the same parameters).

Comment: An example is some of my pages use pagination, the limit of which can be user defined preference. It would simplify the code if I don't need to pass the specific pagination limit via another variable, and instead just retrieve the user preference via another method using the object I already created in init. But there are like 9 of these possible preferences, it would be more ideal to deal with them in a predefined way, and preferably one that doesn't have me store a massive session array or hit the db every time.

Comment: I'd rather put the user preferences in a specific class to encapsulate it and then optimize that class, with object caching, lazy fetching and other such methods. (As user preferences are usually very small amounts of data, optimization will have not a big impact on performance, but maybe on readablity.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118335/discussion-between-pyro4816-and-syck).